# How do I add a separator in my post?

Tags: support

I've just seen someone answer a question and also add additional information on the subject, separated by a horizontal bar, how can I achieve this?[image]

Comment: `<hr>` or `---`

Comment: It is available in the [editing - help](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#horizontal-rules) page

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/323463/edit

Answer (score 18):

You can edit questions with your current reputation by clicking the *edit* button below a question. That way, you can see what that user did at that exact location. You can use this for other features, too.

It would have probably shown you that:

---

is a separator created by using `---`.

### ---

Or it would have shown you that:

---

is a separator created by `<hr>`.

### ---

Finally, you could have chosen to click the separator button:

[image]

### ---

PS: Because I was using the separator for demonstration purposes, I've used this as the separator for my content:

```
---
---
```